# Augmented Reality via (common) Web Cam / iPhone / Android - Grid Detection? - Harry Potter 3D Example

Tags: iphone, android, webcam, augmented-reality, shockwave

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a *basic augmented reality application that uses a piece of (real) paper to navigate (simple rotate, zoom) a virtual 3d or pseudo-3d space.*

The example implementation that comes to mind is the [Harry Potter 3D Augmented Reality ad](http://www.harrypotter3d.com/), where you can take a piece of paper, point it at your webcam (at the right angle/distance), and 3d buildings and such would pop up (on your screen). You can then turn the paper around to rotate the building, or even zoom in.

The example above is done using Shockwave. I'm wondering if there are better web-friendly plugin's, such as Flash (or even HTML5, if webcam integration works?) that might be able to do the same?

Also, are there ways to optimize grid detection, so that the effect is less "lossy" - with the HP example, the buildings often lose their "bearings" on the real paper and just freeze onscreen.

---

It looks like there's already a class (for flash) - portability for iphone(?)
http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/bow_cards.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/augmented_reality.html

It seems to work best with solid-color images though, rather than a complicated map, as in the HP example.

Is it possible to get the cam on an Android or iPhone to do the augmented reality effect?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out [Qualcomm's augmented reality SDK](http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/augmented-reality), you'll free yourself from the Flash layer and you might even win big money in their contest  :)

Comment: i've heard of qualcomm's sdk - looks like it is still only available to a select group of elite developers... when might it be available for the general public?

Answer (score 0):

there is a very easy way with flash/flex AS3.
i am new to developing and managed to build augmented reality program for flash.

for simple tutorials look at  -
www.gotoandlearn.com - great tutorials from lee brimlo, he has 2 or 3 basic tuts for that with code examples.

he basically uses an engine called Flar toolkit.

Another great source is Flar manager. that makes it very easy to implement.

hope it will help.
shani